# Can't setup/connect to database from TwistPHP

Tags: php, mysql

So I've finally got TwistPHP running kind of OK. But I had to set it up (via the GUI wizard) *without* a database. I need database though. So, when I do try to set it up with a database, it gives me an error about missing Database parameters in the Database.twist.php file.

When I look in that file, there's nowhere to enter any values. I have already entered the correct values (DB name, server/address, username, password) in the GUI wizard but it seems as though it's not passing those values on to something when it tries to access the database.

I'm not sure what to do now.

How can I set up/connect to a database with TwistPHP?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest version, in **TwistPHP v3** (https://twistphp.com) the wizard GUI has been made far more intuitive.

**However in answer to your question:**

Open the file /twist/config/config.php and ensure that your database connection details are correct and that the protocol is either mysql or mysqli. If the problem persists send the exact error message that you are getting, I can then advise further.